# How to isolate logical volume group UDID for shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, grep, applescript

I am currently looking to use "diskutil cs list" to show the logical volume groups. I need to be able to isolate the UDID.

Example line from "diskutil cs list"

```
+-- Logical Volume Group B848BCC7-6FFA-4643-AFE1-56FCA333A6B5
```

Previously my though process was to;

```
diskutil cs list | grep 'Group'
```

I think AWK will be a better route to show just the string of letters and numbers. I have been unsuccessful in finding out how to dow so

Ultimately, i will use the UDID in a shell script for reformatting a Fusion drive. Using something similar to below.

```
set a to (do shell script "diskutil cs list|grep 'Group'")
```

I'd like it to set a to the UDID and not the full line.

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
diskutil cs list | awk '/Group/{print $NF}'
```

- `/Group/` will look for lines that have the word `Group` in them. It is just a filter mechanism. If all your output lines have `Group` in them, then you can remove `/Group/` part.
- Once it finds those lines, it will print the last element of that line. `awk` by default splits the line on space.

Comment: If your question is resolved then please don't forget to click the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how new your system is you might have lsblk(1) command, that is made to be combined with scripts. The utility can limit what block devices are listed, and what information is displayed in format that can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
diskutil cs list | grep -Po 'Group \K\S*$'
```